# CONSTRUCT a DISTINCT set of triples by following paths in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases, json-ld, triplestore

I am trying to write a SPARQL query that will extract all relevant triples from a triplestore, using Construct. Essentially, the triplestore is containing a bunch of JSON-LD documents that got parsed into triples, so there is a predictable set of verbs and pattern, and my goal is to reconstruct one of these documents by getting the relevant triples. The documents were JSON objects roughly 7 nested objects deep, and the structure is generally known but any leaf object may have unknown properties I want to get back. So one way I can go about this is:

```
CONSTRUCT WHERE
{
  # get top level object
  ?subject <:knownProperty1> ?v1 .
  ?subject <:knownProperty2> ?v2 .
  ?subject <:knownProperty3> ?v3 .

  # leaf subobjects should get all their fields included
  ?v1 ?v1_p ?v1_o .
  ?v2 ?v2_p ?v2_o .
  ?v3 ?v3_p ?v3_o .

  # v3 has these nested objects.
  ?v3 <:knownNest1> ?n1 .
  ?n1 ?n1_p ?n1_o .

  # n2 is the next level of nesting
  ?n1 <:knownNest2> ?n2 .
  ?n2 ?n2_p ?n2_o .

  #... and so on
}
```

This produces a set of triples that is orders of magnitude larger than the actual document due to duplication -- it is correct but it creates "a graph" for every possible combinatorial match of these values; especially because each level of nesting may have multiple (an array of) subobjects. It gets hairier because many of these known fields are also optional. So for example all the graph matches which assign one concrete value per variable, that include `?subject <:knownProperty1> <:value1>`, supply one copy of that triple, resulting in it being included 100s-1000s of times. In my simple test case that I am using to iterate on, there are 106 triples in the input, and fully specifying the allowed structure as shown above results in a CONSTRUCT result set of 5.5 MILLION triples with a query latency (in RAM) of over 60 seconds.

I can handle writing a complex query but I believe this is a code smell given that the basic problem is not that complicated. So my question is:

1. am I thinking about this wrong ? Is it in fact quite hard in sparql to write a query that would retrieve all the triples following certain paths?
2. is there a convenient way to use SELECT DISTINCT subqueries to shorten this? All my attempts at this are equivalent to "select each distinct comprehensive match on this pattern", which is no better.  I want distinct triples when the pattern matches are combined.

or any other suggestions about the proper way to try this. Thank you!

Comment: Which triplestore? Some produce a graph - a set of triples - no duplicates.

Comment: i don't have control over the triplestore that a consumer of this library will target, but i myself am using Oxigraph at the moment.

Comment: There is nothing like "duplicate triples" in a graph. A particular serialization format may permit the same triple stated multiple times, but the graphs are equivalent in all aspects. There should be no point in tailoring a SPARQL query to a particular shape of the serialized graph, and SPARQL is not made for this purpose anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that this result is inherently a bug in the SPARQL server? Similar behavior is present in a number examples I see online including in SPARQL textbooks which show CONSTRUCT producing results that include multiple representations of one triple for one reason or another ...

Comment: According to [section 16.2 CONSTRUCT](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) of the SPARLQL 1.1 spec: "The result is an RDF graph formed by taking each query solution in the solution sequence, substituting for the variables in the graph template, and _combining the triples into a single RDF graph by set union_" (emphasis mine).  So, strictly speaking, a bug.  Empirically, I have verified that GraphDB, Virtuoso and AllegroGraph all eliminate duplicate triples.  Of course, there may still be performance benefits from generating fewer source triples...

Answer (score 2):

I use the following pattern and process to write construct queries like this.

1. Start with a SELECT and a UNION for each level.

   - to be save don't reuse variable names in different UNION blocks.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{ 
  {
        # get top level object

  } UNION {
        # leaf subobjects should get all their fields included

  } UNION {
        # v3 has these nested objects.

  } UNION {
        # n2 is the next level of nesting

  } UNION {
        #... and so on

  }
}
```

Now you can run the query and verify the output. If all is ok write the
Replace the 'SELECT *' with your CONSTRUCT body.
Imagine your CONSTRUCT template get's called for every line of the table form your SELECT query.

```
CONSTRUCT {
  # get top level object triples
  .... use the variables from UNION block 1 

  # leaf subobjects should get all their fields included
  .... use the variables from UNION block 2
 
  # v3 has these nested objects.
  .... use the variables from UNION block 3

  # n2 is the next level of nesting  
  .... use the variables from UNION block 4

  # and so on ....

}
WHERE
{ 
  {
        # get top level object

  } UNION {
        # leaf subobjects should get all their fields included

  } UNION {
        # v3 has these nested objects.

  } UNION {
        # n2 is the next level of nesting

  } UNION {
        #... and so on

  }
}
```

This approach fits well form me.

1. I avoid unwanted 'duplicates' because I don't mix variables from different union blocks.
2. With starting with a SELECT I can focus on fetching the needed Triples and in the CONSTRUCT part I can focus on Building the graph.
3. Separating different things in different UNIONS help me to debug.
4. I can optimise the query performance of a union block if needed.

Cons: This approach sometimes leads to 'repeat yourself' in the different UNION blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Whether there are duplicate triples (as opposed to unexpected triples genrated by the pattern which are not in the data graph) will depend on the triplestore. It is a trade-off of returning a set (one occurrence of each triple) with scalability for large results (keeping the set of triples stop giving streaming results).

A complicated CONSTRUCT can do this by controlling the pattern:

```
CONSTRUCT { ... }
WHERE {
   SELECT DISTINCT vars needed by template {
      ...
   }
}
```

That looses the ability to use CONSTRUCT WHERE so the template is written twice. CONSTRUCT WHERE is only a convenient short form.

The full CONSTRUCT can have OPTIONAL in the pattern part

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. SELECT DISTINCT unfortunately doesn't help here because it is a DISTINCT over all combinations of all variables. So for example my nesting is 7 layers deep, and a SELECT for the variables would include like `| subj | v1 | v2 | v3 | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 | n6_p | n6_o |` and so on. The combinatorial space of this is roughly as large as the output I am getting -- the entire graph is duplicated as a "prefix" for each `n6 n6_p n6_o .` triple in the result set. In fact this line of thinking makes me suspect my goal is provably infeasible and must rely on iteration.

Comment: I was able to get a DISTINCT and correct result using a property path via the comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253555/how-to-get-all-related-triples-to-a-subject-in-sparql which looks like this: `CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { {SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { <startNode> (!<>)* ?s .  ?s ?p ?o .} }}`. However it will currently go arbitrarily deep. I am looking into limiting it next, and also constraining the verbs. This also concerns me where things like cycles may exist.